# Second sampler runs in continous loop even when first sampler fails

Tags: jmeter

I have an http request sampler1 and extracting a 'JobID' value using regular expression extractor. Now, i have http request sampler2 to check a job status in the same thread group which uses 'JobID' from previous sampler using regular expression extractor. The sampler2 has a while loop controller with condition ${__javaScript("${Status}"!="Ready",)} which is to say keep executing the sampler until status is Ready.

The issue that i am facing is, when the first sampler fails, the second sampler just takes the variable name and keeps trying and never stops because of the while loop.

the second sampler http request gets formed like:

JobID=%24%JobID%7D&request=****

Is there a way to say stop executing the second sampler when first one fails. Any input on this would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

This is how JMeter works, each thread (virtual user) executes [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down (or according to the [Logic Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers))

If you want want to execute 2nd sampler only if first one is successful you need to put your While Controller along with the 2nd sampler under the [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage/) and use `${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}` as the condition

[image]

Where `${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}` is a [pre-defined variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars) holding the result of the previous Sampler

Comment: I tried this. But, after i added the 2nd sampler with while loop under the If Controller, Now the second sampler does not execute at all. The condition that i have added is ${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}==true. I actuall have a JSR223 sampler before this sampler to set the status Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66137941/second-sampler-with-while-loop-controller-stops-after-first-thread. I thought this could be the reason and disabled it. But, even after i disabled, i see that the 2nd sampler does not execute. I am not sure what is happening.

Comment: And, This is what i see from Debug sampler:JMeterThread.last_sample_ok=true

Comment: I changed the condition to just JMeterThread.last_sample_ok which means to check if last sampler is successful and i removed the JSR223 sampler and added a post processor to the previous sampler instead.